# Load model without relationship seems impossible

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, eloquent

after googling and banging my head against the desk for hours I was still unable to solve my various issues with querying relationships the way I want to.

Problem: I have a one-to-many relationship between Article and Comment and Comment and Reply, which works out just fine. In one case though I want to get JUST the Comments + Replies without loading the inverse relationship to Article. How would that be achieved?

I have already given up hope on my original endeavor of loading specific cells from the Article associated to a certain comment. That seems to be even more impossible.

Is my thinking wrong or what's the problem here?

Here are the models:

Article:

```
class Article extends Eloquent{

     protected $table = 'articles';

     protected $softDelete = true;

     protected $fillable = array('short_title','long_title','description','content','zenra_link','source_url','source_title');

     public static $rules = array(
         'short_title'=>'required|min:5',
         'long_title' =>'required',
         'description'=>'required',
         'content'=>'required'
     );

     public function category(){
         return $this->belongsTo('Category');
     }
     public function tag(){
         return $this->belongsToMany('Tag','tagmaps');
     }
     public function comment(){
         return $this->hasMany('Comment');
     }
     public function picture(){
         return $this->hasOne('Picture');
     }
 }
```

Comment:

```
 class Comment extends Eloquent{

      protected $fillable = array('author','content','published','article_id');
      protected $table = 'comment';
      public static $rules = array(
        'author'=>'required|min:5',
        'comment' =>'required|min:10'
      );

      public function reply(){
         return $this->hasMany('Reply');
      }
      public function article(){
         return $this->belongsTo('Article');
      }
 }
```

And last but not least the Replies:

```
 class Reply extends Eloquent{

    protected $fillable = array('author','content','published','comment_id');
    protected $table = 'reply';
    public static $rules = array(
       'author'=>'required|min:5',
       'comment' =>'required|min:5'
    );

    public function comment(){
        return $this->belongsTo('Comment');
    }

 }
```

Question 1: How do I get JUST the comments + replies by comment ID?

Question 2: If possible, can I get comments + replies + specific cell from article by comment ID?

Question 3: How do I get JUST the comment without ANYTHING attached to it by comment ID?

Thank you.

Comment: Impossible is nothing, didn't you know? ;) Write what the problem is exactly because definitely your thinking is wrong here, how you try to: 1 get comments+replies (trivial, unless you want something else to what you say), 2 of course you can, how you try to do that, 3 how you try to get that comment?

Comment: Trivial? Really? I'd love to see that posted as a proper answer if it is so easy.

Comment: Of course, but first edit your question and describe what you need exactly, as fetching single comment without anything attached to it is trivial indeed. I'm eager to help you with Eloquent, but first I need to know what you want.

Comment: I am thoroughly puzzled as to how I can be more specific in what I want. 
1) Fetch comment + replies (and nothing else) by comment ID
2) Fetch comment + replies + specific cell from related article by comment ID
3) Fetch comment (and nothing else) by comment ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
3. Comment::find($commentId); // return Eloquent Model with given id

2. // I suggest renaming relation to replies as there are many replies for a comment
   $comment = Comment::with('replies') // load related replies
      ->with('article') // you want a single field, but better load whole article, then fetch what needed
      ->find($commentId);

   // then:
   $comment->replies; // Collection of related Reply models
   $comment->article->id; // id of related article (or whatever field you want)

1. Comment::with('replies')->find($commentId); // retrieves comment with related replies
```

Comment: 3. Already did that. It returns the comment + all replies + the entire related article. 
2. Basically the same as 3. 
1. Where's the ID? I wanted the comment + replies by ID

Comment: 1 corrected for 1 comment, 2 and 3 - how do you tell it returns all the relations? By any chance not by calling $comment->article or $comment->replies ?

Comment: I accepted your answer and I figured out my problem. After calling Comment::find($commentID) I called $comment->article->title somewhere down the line and wasn't aware of the fact that this stuffs the entire article into the $comment object.

Comment: Be sure to check and understand this too http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading as it's a must to avoid n+1 db calls.